# Hadoop Task Side Effect File Example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can I get an example of how to use task side effect files?

```
public class Map0t extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable >{
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        
         IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ",");
 
        String x;
        String y;
        String z;
                      
        x = tokenizer.nextToken();
        y = tokenizer.nextToken();
        z = tokenizer.nextToken();
                      
        output.collect(new Text(x+" "+z), one);
                       
      }

}
```

I want to write, new Text(x+" "+y), new Text(z) as a side effect in the above Mapper function to a different folder in HDFS.

I searched but could not find any example on how to use task side effect files.

Answer (score 0):

Not an optimum approach, but one way I can think is

> Open a file in HDFS in setup() in the mapper, write into the file and then close the file in the clean() in the mapper. One think to make sure is to use a unique file name in the setup() of the mapper.

Comment: Sripati, Thanks for the reply. I did it with the help of multiple outputs. But, I want to write the output to a different folder, but multiple output just enable me to write to a different named file. Is it possible to write the output from the same mapper or reducer to a different folder? If so can you give the syntax?